# Use or for filter combination

Tags: python, django

I have two query like this below,

Both,It works correctly, but I want to use `OR` for these sentences.

I have ideas to use `Q`

But it has complex filter.

```
cls.objects.filter(point1__gt=0).filter(point1__lt=100)

cld.objects.filter(point2__gt=0).filter(point2__lt=100)
```

Is there any method to use `OR` for this sentenses?

Comment: What do you mean use `OR` for "these sentences"? Can you clarify what results you expect to have in the end with examples? If you know SQL, perhaps you can provide the SQL variant of the query you're aiming for.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try different ORM methods here, take a glance below:

```
cls.objects.filter(point1__range=(0, 100))
cld.objects.filter(point2__range=(0, 100))
```

NOTE that you can do the same with Q function, you said OR above, I think you need AND here.

Links for Django official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#range

Comment: Thank you very much you give me the `range` idea, it's super helpful to shorten the code. But what I want finally is, use or for last two sentences. So what I want to do is concanate these two with `OR`  `objs = cls.objects.filter(point1__in=[0, 100]).filter(point2__in=[0,100]) OR cls.objects.filter(point1__in=[100, 200]).filter(point2__in=[100,200])`

Comment: Is it 1 model here or two models? I mean you wrote cls and cld above and now you write cls only, it would be more understandable to solve it if you give more details about that

Comment: Solved. I use Q multiple times such as `filter(Q(Q(point1__in=[0, 100]),Q(point2__in=[0,100])) | Q(Q(point1__in=[100, 200]),(point2__in=[100,200])))` thank you for your help

Comment: You can work on the readability of the code. Although the problem is solved, it would be better to make it more clean, readable and maintainable)

Comment: The two examples are not equal. The first one checks the range between 0 and 100 where the second example checks for 0 or 100 exactly.

Comment: oh yeah, you're right, that should be done with range

Comment: Ah I made mistook in this reply, SO I update the article to clear the answer.